# How to put header banner image in HTML5

Tags: html, header, banner

I'm just starting with HTML5 and CSS3. My design includes a header banner in top. That is, the logo and banner images all in one banner.

Now, in HTML5, how do I code it?

```
<header>
<figure></figure>
</header>
```

or

```
<header>
<div>Image Header Banner</div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 4):

From your description, you wouldn't use `<figure>` here as you just need to add a logo/images.

The `<figure>` element is used when you need to group images with a caption.

From [w3.org](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/figure.html)

> The figure element represents a unit of content, optionally with a
>   caption, that is self-contained, that is typically referenced as a
>   single unit from the main flow of the document, and that can be moved
>   away from the main flow of the document without affecting the
>   document’s meaning.

Instead you could place images using the `<img />` tag within your `<header>`

```
<header>
 <img />
 <img />
</header>
```

or wrapped in a `<div>` container - depending on what you need.

Also, check out [this article](http://html5doctor.com/the-figure-figcaption-elements/) about the `<figure>` element, in particular at the end of the article says this:

> It may not always be appropriate to use the `<figure>` element, though.
>   For example, a graphic banner should not be marked up with `<figure>`.
>   Instead, simply use the `<img>` element.

Answer (score 0):

```
<header>
    <figure>
        <img src="image" alt="Logo" />
    </figure>
</header>
```

Comment: Thank you Rubens, Danield and Tiago.
I would like to follow what Daniel said.

I used this:

    <header>
    <img src="images/header.jpg">
    </header>